# How to access DBContext inside Task.Run?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I was trying to access the DBContext inside a Task.Run call and it gives me an error.

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Scope disposed{no name, Parent={no name}} is disposed and scoped instances are disposed and no longer available.'
```

For the example code, please check my github repo https://github.com/khertg/EFCoreParallelTest

What am I doing wrong in this part of the code https://github.com/khertg/EFCoreParallelTest/blob/4329b172695de57ee4cb921396f18b36df355454/FunctionApp/Function1.cs#L85?

Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: `DbContext` is not thread-safe, so you shouldn't be doing that in the first place.

Comment: When you're using EF, you should not be using _generic repository anti-pattern_ because your `DbContext` **already is the repository**.

Comment: @Dai so its not advisable to use DBContext inside Task.Run ?

For the generic repository part, it is acknowledged.

Comment: Any alternative for Task.Run ?

Comment: You **can** use a `DbContext` _inside_ a `Task.Run` method, but the `DbContext` _should only exist_ inside that method. So you should create, use, and dispose of the `DbContext` in a single `using` block inside the `Run` callback instead of creating it _outside_ the callback (as well as ensuring there's no concurrent / cross-thread accesses. That said, there's very few good reasons to be using `Task.Run` in the first place - so, why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to implement a functionality that inserts data into the database and after that I want to update redis cache in background.

Comment: You don't need `Task.Run` for that at all. Use your `IHost`'s `IHostedService` capabilities instead. And you can populate Redis directly from SQL Server without going through application code using a Redis connector or SQL Agent job.

Comment: Hmm I also looked into `IHostedService`, however I'm having a hardtime understanding the concept. I'm pretty new to all of this stuff. Thanks for the suggestions and ill look further into `IHostedService`.

Comment: A working example using `IHostedService` would be much appreciated.